# Firebase Notification not getting in my iPhone6

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I implemented firebase notification in my application.Its working fine in my iPhone5.
Both iPhone5 and iPhone6 are using same OS version(10.2.1).
I am sending notification message from firebase dashboard.
Please help me how to solve this issue?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
      [APBConfiguration configuration];

      if( SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN( @"10.0" ) )
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound |    UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];        
}
else
{
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    center.delegate = self;
    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error)
     {
         if( !error )
         {
             [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];  
         }
         else
         {

         }  
     }];  
  }
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    NSLog(@"Device Token :%@",deviceToken);
 }

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {

     NSLog(@"Unable to register for remote notifications: %@", error);
 }
```

Comment: got the answer?

Comment: post your code here

Comment: why sample code? is this what you have tried so far? when is it not appearing? in foreground or background?